# How to set visible false of a Text field

Tags: sapui5

In XML i have :

```
    <Column>
        <m:Text text="TEST page" />
        <template>
        <m:HBox>
        <m:Text text=" BP : {BPOOption}" wrapping="false" id='BP'/>
        <m:Text text=" QTY : {Quantity}" wrapping="false" id='QTY'/>                            
        <m:Text text=" B : {Batch}" wrapping="false" id='Batch'/>
        </m:HBox> 
        </template>   
    </Column>
```

I have seen that default it has `visible='true'` , also checked putting `visible='false'` for each Text field.

What I am trying to achieve is set the Text `visible='false'` using ID's in controller ...

I tried as :

```
var BPText = this.getView().byId('BP');
BPText.setVisible(false);
```

In console...

[image]
But this doesn't work ....Is there any way to set visible or hide a text field , any help is appreciated TIA

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210736/discussion-on-question-by-codenewbie-how-to-set-visible-false-of-a-text-field).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Marc and @cmdd comment's ....the solution is as :

No more id's required ,

`<m:Text text=" BP : {BPOOption}" wrapping="false" visible="{= !!${BPOOption} }"/>`